# Read txt file via php according to user searched keyword?

Tags: php

I need to know how I can read a txt file via PHP and display the result according to what the user searched for via a textfield?

I found this PHP code but I don't know how I can implement a textfield box into it.

```
  <?php
$file = 'somefile.txt';
$searchfor = '';

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}

?>
```

I did try something like this but didn't work:

```
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="something" value="<?php $searchfor ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tweak it a little bit,  no need to add a value to input.
When you post a page the value gets submitted so remove `value="<?php $searchfor ?>"`

Here is how the script should be:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['something'])) {
    $file = 'form.txt';
    $searchfor = '';
    // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $searchfor = $_POST['something'];
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
       echo "Found matches:\n";
       echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
    }
    else{
       echo "No matches found";
    }
    header('Content-Type: text/html');
    }
?>

  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="something" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>
```

Comment: this also works but the php will show all the txt file content on page load!  do you know how I can prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = 'somefile.txt';
$searchfor = '';

if (!empty($_POST['something'])) {
    // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    // escape special characters in the query
    $pattern = $_POST['something'];
    // finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
    $pattern = "/^.*($pattern).*\$/m";
    // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
       echo "Found matches:\n";
       var_dump($matches); 
    }
    else{
       echo "No matches found";
    }
    exit; // since it is parsed as plaintext, you can't use the html form below anyway
}

?>

  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="something" value="<?php $searchfor ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>
```

---

Things changed:

1. Check if $_POST['something'] is set before searching.
2. Removed `$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');` as I always got double slashes with it. You might re-check that though.
3. Actually set `$pattern` to `$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');` or else you will never get the user input.
4. Exit the script (see comment).
5. Note that I used `var_dump($matches)`. Else, when using sub matches you might not get the correct output.

Comment: This works good but the result returned is in weird format! like this: Found matches: array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(25) "Apple" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "Apple" } } instead of showing just Apple! any idea?